# Inline block pushing over two lines

Tags: javascript, css, command-line-interface

I want to make an old school command line interface for this web app. I can't seem to get the crucial detail of the command prompt and input area working as should.

It should be on the same line. How can I make it so?

My attempt uses inline block on both the prompt and the contenteditable div.

The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Aq4A/), I think the problem could be in the CSS:

```
.ux-command-container {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    font-size:0px;
    height:0px;
    margin:auto;
}
.ux-command-line {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:12px;
    width:90%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    line-height:12px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.ux-command-line:focus {
    outline:none;
}
.ux-command-prompt {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:12px;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the

```
white-space: pre
```

from the

```
.ux-panel
```

declaration